# Cat meows when being pet

Tags: cats, behavior

Two cats. One is rough and tumble, (Nora) , the other small and sweet, (Luna)

They are sisters and have been in our care two years from birth.

Nora will seek out attention from me. And when I pet her, she runs away, calls for me to follow.

I pet her again. She rolls her side as I pet her. She rolls over, as I pet her other side. She stands up, nuzzles my hand, then falls on her side, I pet her. She meows occasionally during each sequence of this.

Luna has never done this.

Food, water, litter, and toy emergencies are not happening.

I understand cats share emotions differently. Is this Nora's way of showing affection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my cat walk away (and expect me to follow) while I stroke her?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/285/why-does-my-cat-walk-away-and-expect-me-to-follow-while-i-stroke-her)

Answer (score 5):

Fall over is usually "I acknowledge you as the dominant member of our clowder." Plus "if I do this humans seem to respond favorably."

For pets, 'cute' is a survival skill.

Answer (score 1):

Cats are simply different, just like we humans are.

Did you know that cats only meow at humans? They don't meow at other cats, but they have plenty of ways to communicate with their comrades.

Meowing is, for some reason, reserved for humans.

When I first heard this I thought it was nonsense. Then I got to thinking and I could not remember a time one of our cats (we have had A LOT of cats)  meowed at another. And I began watching for it and have never seen - well, that is - heard them do it.

SimonT